# Using jquery to swap text, how to revert other text to original?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

So I have a bit of jquery that I am using to swap "View Bio" for "Hide Bio" and vice versa for multiple profiles. Works great, only I'm not sure how to make it so that when you click a different profile's "View Bio" while one's "Hide Bio" is active, the other profile's "Hide Bio"s reverts back to the original "View Bio".

Basically, I want to only have one saying "Hide Bio" at all times (making it the only active bio).
Also I want it so I can still click the one that currently says "Hide Bio" to make it say "View Bio" (i.e. All profiles say "View Bio")

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pauljackson/2zn4X/

(EDIT - updated fiddle with solution implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/pauljackson/2zn4X/2/)

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".viewbio").click(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        if ($self.text().trim() == "VIEW BIO")
        $self.text("HIDE BIO");
        else
        $self.text("VIEW BIO");
    });
});
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="ourteamslide">
<div class="maincontent">
<div class="ourteamlist">
            <ul>
                <li>                        
                    <img src="http://eldoradospringsmo.com/pages/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/wpid-WP_IM_1404400872566__0.jpg" class="profilepic" alt="Profile Pic">
                    <div class="lilbluebox">
                        <div class="teambox">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <p class="whitetext">Some Dude</p>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="viewbio">VIEW BIO</div>
                                                                        </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>                        
                    <img src="http://eldoradospringsmo.com/pages/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/wpid-WP_IM_1395933210796__1.jpg" class="profilepic" alt="Profile Pic">
                    <div class="lilbluebox">
                        <div class="teambox">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <p class="whitetext">Some Gal</p>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="viewbio">VIEW BIO</div>                             
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>                        
                    <img src="http://ind.ccio.co/I/g5/U9/4ea7744cfd95a0b491203004e516808f.jpg?iw=300" class="profilepic" alt="Profile Pic">
                    <div class="lilbluebox">
                        <div class="teambox">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <p class="whitetext">Some Old Man</p>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="viewbio">VIEW BIO</div>
                                                                        </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size:12px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.maincontent{
max-width:1240px;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding-right:30px;
}
#ourteamslide{
height:auto;
background-color:#eeeeee;
padding-top:80px;
}
.whitetext{
color:#000000;
width:200px;
}
.ourteamlist{
max-width:1200px;
height:1000px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:10px;
background-color:#eeeeee;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
margin-left:-1px;
clear:both;
}
.ourteamlist ul li{
display:inline-block;
margin-right:-3px;
text-align:left;
margin-top:1px;
}
.profilepic{
height:205px;
width:299px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-bottom:1px;
}
.lilbluebox{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin-top:-5px;
width:299px;
height:80px;
}
.teambox{
padding-left:30px;
padding-top:20px;
width:100%;
}
.teambox ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
.viewbio{
font-size:11px;
font-weight:600;
text-align:right;
margin-right:30px;
color:#888888;
cursor:pointer;
}
.biobox{
display:block;
background-color:#1E2129;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding-left:30px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-right:30px;
max-width:600px;
}
.teambox ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is select and set all the links to "View Bio" before changing the clicked link to "Hide Bio".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".viewbio").click(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        var originalText = $self.text().trim();

        $(".viewbio").text("VIEW BIO");

        if (originalText == "VIEW BIO") {
            $self.text("HIDE BIO");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! One thing, though, what can I do to make it so I can still click the one that says "Hide Bio" to make it say "View Bio" (i.e. All profiles say "View Bio")?

Comment: Ah, then all you have to do is re-introduce your if-statement. I'll edit that in for you.

Comment: Sorry Ben I should have mentioned that specifically, I'll edit my q for future viewers. Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and KJ's? They both do the same thing, just wondering if one is structured better than the other or just differently.

Comment: I would say that mine is less complex and more efficient because it doesn't use an extra selector, also it eliminates the need for an else statement. Whatever works though!

Comment: The extra selector should make it more efficient.  `$(".viewbio")` selects *all* of the elements with this class. `$(".viewbio:contains('HIDE BIO')")` will cut down on run time, not by a lot, but it's good practice to make your javascript fast.

Comment: Got curious, I felt that the extra contains selector would be slower than selecting all. Created a test here that shows it to be slower indeed! http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-query-speed

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with css and a separate element for the text "hide" and "view"

HTML

```
<div class="viewbio">
   <span class="view">View</span>
   <span class="hide">Hide</span> 
   Bio
</div>
```

CSS

```
.viewbio .hide, .viewbio.active .view {
   display:none;
}

.viewbio.active .hide {
   display: inline;
}
```

Then just select all viewbio's that are active and remove the active class, and then add the active class to the clicked on.

```
$(".viewbio").click(function(){
    var wasActive = $(this).hasClass("active");
    $(".viewbio.active").removeClass("active");
    if(!wasActive) $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/ANpNQ/4/)

Comment: Nice, this works great as well, although in my instance Ben's is simpler to implement. Still same issue that I mentioned to Ben about the ability to click "Hide Bio" and make it saw "View Bio" (to make all profiles say "View Bio")

Comment: already modified to do that, plus this does not hard code the text in your javascript. That way you can change the text of the viewbio element to whatever and not have to care about going back into the js to change it.

Comment: As I said to Ben, sorry I should have mentioned that specifically. Thanks!

Comment: Good point, in this case it won't matter but that's great info to know for future uses.

Comment: This is a good answer as well, I also prefer not to hard code values.

Answer (score 1):

This will select the items that have "HIDE BIO" and change those plus the item that you clicked.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".viewbio").click(function() {
            var $self = $(this);
           if ($self.text().trim() == "VIEW BIO"){
               $(".viewbio:contains('HIDE BIO')").text("VIEW BIO");
               $self.text("HIDE BIO");
           }
           else{
               $self.text("VIEW BIO");

           }
        });
    });
```